# How do I force NetworkManager to encrypt stored passwords?

Tags: wireless, network-manager, encryption, wpa-supplicant

In ubuntu 14.04 `NetworkManager` stores the passwords for networks in the file `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/<ESSID_of_AP>` in plaintext.

I'm not sure if it relies on `wpa_supplicant` for making the handshake, which I've used to make wireless connections from the command line, and I know for a fact, allows you to store the WPA-PSK in cipher-text. I'm still doing the research now, (It's part of a larger effort) but was wondering if there was a known option, a boolean switch somewhere in the config that I could change to force it to negotiate the handshake with the encrypted value.

Comment: Well, yeah but you need the sudo password to access the password unless the system is not running. If you are interested in restricting access when the filesystem is not running, you can encrypt the entire drive. I get what you are saying but if someone has sudo access, they have access to anything and everything regardless of encryption anyhow.

Comment: Also, you may want to check to see if your question has been asked on security.stackexchange.com

Comment: I get that, UID=0 ~> you lose. And that the perms for those files are 600. I'm just going stepping an audit/hardening process, and am trying to account for everything I find.